# How to insert the text below subplot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to

```
#Plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
gs1.update(wspace=0.025, hspace=0.05)  # set the spacing between axes.

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1])
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_xlabel('(a)')
ax2.axis('off')
ax2.set_xlabel('(b)')
```

Because I must turn off axis in the figure, hence, I used `ax1.axis('off')`. Now, I want to insert the figure description such as (a),(b) below each subplot. I used `xlabel` but it cannot work due to function `axis('off')`. I can have other options by using `.text` function, but it requires the known position. In my case, the text must be below and center in each subplot. How can I implement it. Thanks
My expected result is

[image]

Comment: If `axis("off")` is set, the xlabel is removed from the figure (together with all other artists that are part of the axis). You have two options: (1) keep axis on and remove all parts of the axis manually, except the xlabel. (2) add a text label below the subplot. For which of the two options would you need help?

Comment: I think the second option. Could you write it by code? I am thanks if you show first option also

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is if `axis("off")` is set, the xlabel is [removed from the figure](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/bcc2f12493081b27b9900658ef6500d2b39cc0ab/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L2357) (together with all other artists that are part of the axis).

However, you may use some normal text label just below the axes to mimic the xlabel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
gs1.update(wspace=0.025, hspace=0.05)  # set the spacing between axes.

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0])
ax1.imshow([[0,1],[2,1]])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[1])
ax2.imshow([[2,1],[0,1]])

ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')

ax1.text(0.5,-0.1, "(a) my label", size=12, ha="center", 
         transform=ax1.transAxes)
ax2.text(0.5,-0.1, "(b) my other label", size=12, ha="center", 
         transform=ax2.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Changing the `-0.1` will give you more or less space between the axes and the text.